# Calling a widget with a function as a parameter in Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, parameters, widget

I am trying to call a custom widget that has a function as a parameter, however I got no clue what parameter I could assign to it. I have tested all the ideas I came up with but with no success. The idea for this, I have gained from a tutorial, however I have done some things differently, as I have different requirements.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function addTx;
  const NewTransaction({Key? key, required this.addTx}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('I cant solve this problem');
  }
}
```

========================================================================

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:function_parameter_problem/new_transaction.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NewTransaction(
                addTx:
                    addTx), // What parameter can/should I pass here? It is crucial for my project
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Okay, but let's say that the `NewTransaction()` function returnes a scaffold with appbar, etc and I have to call it again, however in the following scenario:

```
_wykonajZapytanie() { //function called onPressed in the main window
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewTransaction()),
    ); /*I have to put a parameter here, but I just want to display another window, I don't know why, but I just can't get any ideas*/
  }
```

**IMPORTANT TO NOTICE** In the original project, if it comes to the first example I have provided, I do not call NewTransaction(addTx...) in the main class, but in the UserTransaction class.

**tldr** I need to assemble an expandable list in the main class - which can be done the way below from what I know, but also I need to call this function in the the main class on the onPressed of a button to display all of the textfields, etc.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './new_transaction.dart';
import './transaction_list.dart';
import '../models/transaction.dart';

class UserTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserTransactionState createState() => _UserTransactionState();
}

class _UserTransactionState extends State<UserTransaction> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    Transaction(
        id: 1,
        date: DateTime.now(),
        numTel: 911911911,
        // scoring: 'Link wygasł',
        user: 'Polizei pau pau'),
    Transaction(
        id: 2,
        date: DateTime.now(),
        numTel: 911911911,
        // scoring: 'Link wygasł',
        user: 'Tha police')
  ];

  void _addNewTransaction(int txNumTel, /* String txScoring,*/ String txUser) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      numTel: txNumTel,
      /*scoring: txScoring,*/
      user: 'PLZ WORK',
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: 3,
    );
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback function; 
  //if nothing returns
  //else typedef CustomFunc = Function(int param); (replace int with your data type)
  const NewTransaction({Key? key, required this.function}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
            child: Text('I cant solve this problem'),
            onTap:function,
            //if custom 
            //onTap: (){
            // function(params);
            //}
          );
  }
}

Call like below...

body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            NewTransaction(
                function: (){
                    //todo  
                  },
                //if custome function: (params){ todo },
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this is the way you can pass a function with parameters:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() addTx;
  const NewTransaction({Key? key, required this.addTx}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('I cant solve this problem');
  }
}
```

When passing this Function, make sure to pass it like this: `NewTransaction(addTx: () => addTx());`. If you pass it like this: `NewTransaction(addTx: addTx());` the function gets called instantly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say`Function addTx` it means any function can be passed.
If `Function() addTx` it means function with no parameter.
If `Function(int) addTx` it means function with one required positional parameter integer.
If  `void Function() addTx` it means function with no parameter and return type should be void.

In flutter you can also use
`VoidCallback` which is basically `void Function()` written like this
`final VoidCallback addTd`.
.
or can use `ValueChanged<T>` which is basically `void Function(T value)`

More info at:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions